# How to create an auto increment java variable

Tags: java, auto-increment, uniqueidentifier

I am currently building a mock Hospital administration system. I have successfully been able to write user registration inputs such as name, gender etc. from jTextFields into a text file but I am struggling with the idea of making an auto incrementing unique identifier that changes with each new line of the text file. I have a jTextField dedicated towards it but have been unsuccessful in making the int variable increase by 1 each time the Add record button is clicked.

I have declared "reg" as an integer equal to 1

```
int reg = 1;
```

Because I need to send the number to a text file I convert it to a string and set the uneditable textfield regnumber to that string before it writes to the text file

```
 String regString = Integer.toString(reg);
        regnumber.setText(regString);
```

Unfortunately reg continues to appear as 2 when it gets written to the file. How and at what point to I use the ++ operator to increase reg number in the texfield every time the frame is loaded. Any help would be much appreciated

[screenshot of GUI in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izGuF.jpg)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so that we have more context for what you are trying to do.

Comment: You are going to have to increment `regNumber` by 1 once you are done writing to the file. So the next write is `regNumber` + 1. Also note that if you close the program, you are going to have to read from the file to find the last `regNumber` recorded into it and add one. That way your new inserts have an updated `regNumber` when the program is running, and when it's first opened with records in the file already.

Comment: You need a "manager" class which does this functionality, calling "next" will return the next value and increment it internally.  It could also be used to save/load the value from an external source so you can continue using it between runs

Comment: I hope this could help https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html

Answer (score 1):

Read the value from the file only once and initialize it to an [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html). Use `incrementAndGet()` method to increment and obtain the current value by one.

```js
    private static AtomicInteger at = new AtomicInteger(0);
    
    public int getNextCountValue() {
        return at.incrementAndGet();
    }
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You have not included enough detail in your Question to know for sure what the issue is, but here is my guess.

## Left-side versus right-side

- The [*postfix* operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) `++` & `--`, meaning on the right-side of a variable, take effect *after* the value from the variable is accessed.
- When on the left-side of the variable, they take effect *before* the value is accessed.

See [the demo in the Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) by Oracle. I suggest you take time to study these tutorials, as they cover all the basics of learning Java.

```
// prints 5
System.out.println(i);
// prints 6
System.out.println(++i);
// prints 6
System.out.println(i++);
// prints 7
System.out.println(i);
```